# Equivalent System of equations

Tags: linear-programming, matrix-equations

Let system
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{A_1}X = {b_1}\\
a_1^TX = {b_2}
\end{array} \right.$$
where the last constraint is dependent to others.
Prove that if this system be a feasible system then it is equivalent to system $AX=b$.